# Rails - Devise - Disable Reset Password Token expiration time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-recoverable

I currently working on a Rails app with devise authentication. I need to disabled the token expiration for reset password. According to [Devise Documentation on Recoverable](https://rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable) there is not configuration to do that. The only method I think to make this works is to override Recoverable and the `reset_password_period_valid?` function to always return true. But I not sure if is the best/proper solution.

Current on my devise.rb I have:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 2.hours
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as 10 years, for example, and it will be like disabled token expiration.

Comment: Yes, I propose that but i found a better solution using `devise-invitable` gem.